# Numpy error when specifying axis in nanmax while nansum works an the same case

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, max, nan

I am trying to get the max of numpy.arrays like in the following code:

```
[np.nanmax(temp_data[i:i+window_size, 1:], axis=0) for i, t in enumerate(temp_data)]
```

Though, I get the following error:

```
{TypeError}ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Anyways, if instead of `nanmax`, I use `nansum`, like in the following code, everything works smoothly:

```
[np.nansum(temp_data[i:i+window_size, 1:], axis=0) for i, t in enumerate(temp_data)]
=> A 9x2 requested np.array
```

Moreover, this to codes, with either `nanmax` or  `nansum` both work:

```
[np.nansum(temp_data[i:i+window_size, 1:]) for i, t in enumerate(temp_data)]
[np.nanmax(temp_data[i:i+window_size, 1:]) for i, t in enumerate(temp_data)]
=> A 9x1 np.array, (but this is not what I want)
```

Any idea, why specifying the axis in `nanmax` fails while it works for `nansum` ?

Edit: example of temp_data:

```
    temp_data = np.array([[datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 1, 0, 0), np.nan, np.nan],
                          [datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 2, 0, 0), np.nan, np.nan],
                          [datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 3, 0, 0), np.nan, np.nan],
                          [datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 4, 0, 0), np.nan, np.nan],
                          [datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 7, 0, 0), np.nan, 1],
                          [datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 8, 0, 0), np.nan, 2],
                          [datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 9, 0, 0), 1, 3],
                          [datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 10, 0, 0), 5, 4],
                          [datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 11, 0, 0), 4, 1]])
```

Comment: What's the dtype of `temp_data`?

Comment: @Divakar : I updated my Question with a sample of `temp_data`

Comment: How are you importing `datetime`?

Comment: Import datetime, but there is no issue with my datetimes, they work great in the rest of the code, and are excluded from the `nanmax` calculation since I only take `1:` on the second dimension.

Comment: FYI: I created a numpy issue for the underlying problem: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could force `float` conversion on the data, as numpy doesn't seem to know how to handle the data when they have the `object` type:

```
#                                              \/
>>> [np.nanmax(temp_data[i:i+window_size, 1:].astype(float), axis=0) for i, t in enumerate(temp_data)]
[array([ nan,  nan]),
 array([ nan,  nan]),
 array([ nan,  nan]),
 array([ nan,   1.]),
 array([ nan,   2.]),
 array([ 1.,  3.]),
 array([ 5.,  4.]),
 array([ 5.,  4.]),
 array([ 4.,  1.])]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is either a bug or the result of undefined behavior in numpy.  Your array `temp_data` has dtype `object`.  That means the values in the array can be arbitrary Python objects.  The error that you see is what happens when you give an object array to `nanmax` and specify an axis.

Here's a simple example, using numpy version 1.12.1:

```
In [21]: a = np.array([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]], dtype=object)

In [22]: np.nanmax(a, axis=0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-a020f98a2536> in <module>()
----> 1 np.nanmax(a, axis=0)

/Users/warren/miniconda3scipy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py in nanmax(a, axis, out, keepdims)
    343         # Fast, but not safe for subclasses of ndarray
    344         res = np.fmax.reduce(a, axis=axis, out=out, **kwargs)
--> 345         if np.isnan(res).any():
    346             warnings.warn("All-NaN slice encountered", RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
    347     else:

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

The function does not raise an error when `axis` is not specified`:

```
In [23]: np.nanmax(a)
Out[23]: 4.0
```

`nansum()` handles an axis properly:

```
In [24]: np.nansum(a, axis=0)
Out[24]: array([4.0, 6.0], dtype=object)
```

If the objects in the array are all convertible to Python floating point values, you can use the `astype()` method to convert the array to one with data type `numpy.float64`, for which `nanmax()` works as expected:

```
In [26]: a.astype(np.float64)
Out[26]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.]])

In [27]: np.nanmax(a.astype(np.float64), axis=0)
Out[27]: array([ 3.,  4.])
```